# Git command to get id's of opened merge requests

Tags: git, terminal, gitlab, git-merge, merge-request

refs/merge-requests/*/head

return all list of merge request (merged & opened)

is it possible to get id's of opened requests only? without gitlab cli

all merge requests: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
closed: 1, 2, 3

git terminal command return only: 4, 5

Comment: Git really doesn’t track pull requests

Comment: Thanks for answer, looks like i cant get a status of MR too?  So, any solutions to handle it?

I wanted create sh script that will check opened MR and open them in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`glab` CLI from GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/glab/) instead of relying on Git refspecs alone.

[`glab mr list`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/main/docs/source/mr/list.md) should be close to what you are looking for:

It does not show the status (see [issues 1283](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/issues/1283)), but it show MR closed only, or merged only.